# Выбор средства разработки платформера

Tags: c#

Есть цель сделать 2D платформер. Лучше написать свой движок или проще использовать готовый? Хочу знать точно в каком направлении пойти. Нужна объективная точка зрения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Писать свой движок с нуля бессмысленно. Свой движок писать нужно только в том случае, если не устраивает оптимизация или возможности ни одного из существующих. И только в этом случае.

В твоем случае тебе подойдет любой из движков которые работают с тем языком, который ты знаешь.

Comment: "И только в этом случае" - позвольте с Вами не согласиться, в образовательных целях - это отличный способ понять многое в программировании

Comment: @StrangerintheQ эта цель никак не связана с его целью написать 2д платформер. В случае его цели - это бессмысленно.

Comment: Ну Вы же не первый день здесь, это увидит и прочитает не только автор вопроса...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ если человек знает что его цель "написать движок в образовательных целях", то он не будет гуглить ЭТОТ вопрос.

Comment: @Andrew да я уже понял что Вы все про всех знаете

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а что тут знать? Если человек уже знает что он хочет ("писать движок в образовательных целях"), он не будет гуглить **нужно ли** писать свой движок под платформер. Он будет гуглить **как реализовать конкретную фичу** движка.

Comment: @Andrew да, да я про это и говорю, все про всех знаете, молодец.